# Math specification with a Regression with SARIMA errors

Tags: r, time-series, regression, arima, sarimax

I have one question so I'm asking for your help.

I'm working on a model with a Regression with `SARIMA` errors, I already have the model and the forecast, but I need the mathematically specification for the model, the order is (1,1,0) (1,0,0,12), and here we have the coefficients, so how can I build the model if the algebraic example is this one? Because I can’t understand how to specify the model for this case with a regression

```
Regression with ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,0,0)[12] errors 

Coefficients:
ar1   0.3972   
sar1  -0.4102  
xreg  0.0380
         
s.e.       
ar1    0.1108 
sar1   0.1216 
xreg   0.0113
```

I really appreciate your help.

I already specify the model with `Rstudio`, and estimate the forecast, so the only thing I need is the model specify to complete with this task, but I don't know how to do it with the regression.